# Searching Wikipedia API on titles which are embeddedin a template

Tags: wikipedia-api

I want to query the Wikipedia API for information found in the infobox video games template. So, I make the following API call to get a list of pages which have the infobox video games template embedded in them:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=embeddedin&geititle=template:infobox%20video%20game](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=embeddedin&geititle=template%3ainfobox%20video%20game)

And I get the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api>
  <query-continue>
    <embeddedin geicontinue="10|Infobox_video_game|8484" />
  </query-continue>
  <query>
    <pages>
      <page pageid="785" ns="0" title="Asteroids (video game)" />
      <page pageid="2215" ns="0" title="Sid Meier&#039;s Alpha Centauri" />
      <page pageid="4098" ns="0" title="Puzzle Bobble" />
      <page pageid="4965" ns="0" title="Bubble Bobble" />
      <page pageid="6023" ns="0" title="Castle of the Winds" />
      <page pageid="6259" ns="0" title="Civilization (video game)" />
      <page pageid="6614" ns="0" title="Chrono Trigger" />
      <page pageid="7431" ns="0" title="Counter-Strike" />
      <page pageid="7840" ns="0" title="Chrono Cross" />
      <page pageid="8090" ns="0" title="Day of the Tentacle" />
    </pages>
  </query>
</api>
```

Great. Perfect. Now, I don't want a list of all such pages, because that's almost totally useless. I want a list of all such pages that match "mario." So I make the following API call.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=embeddedin&geititle=template:infobox%20video%20game&list=search&srsearch=mario](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=embeddedin&geititle=template%3ainfobox%20video%20game&list=search&srsearch=mario)

And I get the following result (truncated to 2 results for readability)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api>
  <query-continue>
    <search sroffset="10" />
    <embeddedin geicontinue="10|Infobox_video_game|8484" />
  </query-continue>
  <query>
    <pages>
      <page pageid="785" ns="0" title="Asteroids (video game)" />
      <page pageid="2215" ns="0" title="Sid Meier&#039;s Alpha Centauri" />
    </pages>
    <searchinfo totalhits="39118" />
    <search>
      <p ns="0" title="Mario" snippet="is a fictional character  in the &lt;span class=&#039;searchmatch&#039;&gt;Mario&lt;/span&gt; video game franchise  by Nintendo , created by Japanese video game designer  Shigeru Miyamoto .  &lt;b&gt;...&lt;/b&gt; " size="58561" wordcount="8141" timestamp="2014-03-16T02:28:37Z" />
      <p ns="0" title="Mario (disambiguation)" snippet="&lt;span class=&#039;searchmatch&#039;&gt;Mario&lt;/span&gt;  is a fictional character in his eponymous video game series. &lt;span class=&#039;searchmatch&#039;&gt;Mario&lt;/span&gt; may also refer to:  People : &lt;span class=&#039;searchmatch&#039;&gt;Mario&lt;/span&gt; (given name), a list of people  &lt;b&gt;...&lt;/b&gt; " size="1354" wordcount="189" timestamp="2013-08-26T18:46:18Z" />
    </search>
  </query>
</api>
```

Which is also perfect, except not so much, because it gave me essentially two separate query results in the same call, which is a use case for never. Is there a way I can query the results that I get from an embeddedin list, or is the wikipedia API basically useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is not “basically useless”, but it won't work for your particular kind of query.

One way to work around that would be to use [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/About), which extracts information from Wikipedia infoboxes and can be queried using SPARQL.

To get all video games that contain `Mario` in their title, you could use something like:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
    ?game rdf:type dbpedia-owl:VideoGame.
    ?game rdfs:label ?label.
    FILTER regex(?label, "Mario")
}
```

Or, maybe even better, get all games in the Super Mario series:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Super_Mario_(series)> dbpprop:game ?game
}
```